# nginx server not starting it throw an error bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: docker, symfony, nginx, docker-compose

I am configuring php symfony basic welcome page project into docker i am using image

[richarvey nginx-php-fpm](https://github.com/richarvey/nginx-php-fpm)

this have all packages that i need to run php framework with docker (nginx, php,alpine, docker tags)
my nginx server is not working, when wrote nginx in my terminal(Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS)  i am getting the following error

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

**DIR**

```
project
├── app       
├── .git               
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
└── README.md
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:   test-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: test-app-container
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest

ENV WEBROOT="/var/www/html/public"

COPY app/* /var/www/html/

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

Comment: Ports below 1024 requires root-privileges. It seems like such an error.

Comment: so i need to change my ports from docker-compose.yml  with following 8080:8080 or any other port number which greater than 80

Comment: as i change the port it throw same error in terminal.

Comment: let me know do i change it from etc/nginx/default.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it there was issue with image version and also issue with user permission ,for that purpose i have add the envirnement variables for owner and group for the project build to create a container for the required images

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  test-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: test-app-container
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/var/www/html/
    environment:
      PGID: 1000
      PUID: 1000
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```